# Load an obj file using ThreeJS

Tags: three.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <script src="https://meadowdecor.jackzc.com/smple/node_modules/three/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://meadowdecor.jackzc.com/smple/node_modules/three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="https://meadowdecor.jackzc.com/smple/node_modules/three/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
    <script src="https://meadowdecor.jackzc.com/smple/node_modules/three/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>

    <script>

        const height = window.innerHeight;
        const width = window.innerWidth;
        const texture_file = 'https://meadowdecor.jackzc.com/smple/source/texture.jpg';
        const model_file = 'https://meadowdecor.jackzc.com/smple/source/5.obj';

        /**
         * Generate a scene object with a background color
         **/
        function createScene() {
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x111111);

            return scene;
        }

        /**
         * Generate the camera to be used in the scene. Camera args:
         *   [0] field of view: identifies the portion of the scene
         *     visible at any time (in degrees)
         *   [1] aspect ratio: identifies the aspect ratio of the
         *     scene in width/height
         *   [2] near clipping plane: objects closer than the near
         *     clipping plane are culled from the scene
         *   [3] far clipping plane: objects farther than the far
         *     clipping plane are culled from the scene
         **/
        function createCamera() {
            const aspectRatio = width / height;
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspectRatio, 0.1, 1000);
            camera.position.set(0, 1, 10);

            return camera;
        }

        /**
       * Generate the light to be used in the scene. Light args:
       *   [0]: Hexadecimal color of the light
       *   [1]: Numeric value of the light's strength/intensity
       *   [2]: The distance from the light where the intensity is 0
       * @param {obj} scene: the current scene object
       **/
        function createLights(scene) {

            const light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 0);
            light1.position.set(1, 1, 1);
            scene.add(light1);

            // An ambient light
            const light2 = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x111111);
            scene.add(light2);

        }

        /**
        * Generate the renderer to be used in the scene
        **/
        function createRenderer() {

            // Create the canvas with a renderer
            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, preserveDrawingBuffer: true });

            // Add support for retina displays
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

            renderer.setClearColor("#fff");

            // Specify the size of the canvas
            renderer.setSize(width, height);

            // Add the canvas to the DOM
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
            return renderer;

        }

        /**
        * Generate the controls to be used in the scene
        * @param {obj} camera: the three.js camera for the scene
        * @param {obj} renderer: the three.js renderer for the scene
        **/
        function createControls(camera, renderer) {
            const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            controls.zoomSpeed = 0.4;
            controls.panSpeed = 0.4;

            return controls;
        }

        function createTexture() {
            var texture_loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            var texture = texture_loader.load(texture_file);
            texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            texture.repeat.set(1, 1);
            texture.needsUpdate = true;
        }

        /**
         * Load object
         **/
        function loadModel() {

            const loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            loader.load(model_file, function (object) {
                // object.rotation.z = Math.PI;
                // object.scale.set(2,2,2);
                // object.position.set(1, 1, 1);
                object.frustumCulled = false;
                scene.add(object);
            });

        }

        /**
         * Render!
         **/

        function render() {
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            controls.update();
        };

        //==========================================================================================//

        var scene = createScene();
        var camera = createCamera();
        var renderer = createRenderer();
        var controls = createControls(camera, renderer);

        createLights(scene);
        loadModel(scene);
        render();

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Just starting to learn ThreeJS, I downloaded an obj file and tried to load it into a web page using ThreeJS, it worked! However, it works not the way I want, I expect the object shows in the middle of my screen, but it doesn't. I have to hold the left button on the mouse and drag it to the right, then the object shows! And it's smaller than I expected!

Here is the code below, and as I said before, I am very new toThreeJS, I spent 2 days trying to figure this out and I failed. THANK YOU for any kind of help.

PS:

1. Here is the obj file I am using: [Download it from my Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1foJNs4pGAWPxaNKVadwdcL3TT1Khm3si/view?usp=sharing)
2. I try to upload this obj file into some online 3D reviewer programs, and it shows very well!

Update:

The model behaves like it uses my mouse coordinate as its origin, but with a distance. [Click here](https://meadowdecor.jackzc.com/smple/index.html) to see the effect (you have to hold the left button on your mouse and move it to find the model).

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, to solve the object being too small, you can scale it:

```js
model.scale.set(2, 2, 2); //Double
```

For not being centered, your model might not be at the origin (when it was created). You can either fix the model, or change the model's position in `three.js` using `model.position`. If your object is not showing up properly, the try adding:

```js
object.frustumCulled = false;
```

That should do it~

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am guessing that I should put these two lines here: 

        function loadModel() {

            const loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            loader.load(model_file, function (object) {
                object.scale.set(2,2,2);
                object.frustrumCulled = false;
                scene.add(object);
            });

        }

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: Let's address one problem at a time. Does your model appear larger?

Comment: I also made a typo. `frustrumCulled` should be `frustumCulled`. I edited my answer

Comment: It doesn't appear larger, actually, it appears nothing on screen, just black background after I added the first line: object.scale.set(2,2,2).

Comment: It might be because of the `culling`. Did you fix my typo?

Comment: I don't know if this is my illusion, seems like this object using my mouse coordinate as its origin, but with a distance.

Comment: Could you provide a snippet so I could take a look?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244115/discussion-between-jack-and-anye).

Comment: OK, after almost a week of struggling, I finally get it to work.  It's actually quite simple because the 3D model I downloaded was not centered! After trying another model which centered, all works fine.

Comment: You actually pointed out the problem but I was just confused with something else, I'm going to mark your post as an answer, Very much appreciated your help!